# Wordpress Rewrite Page Parameters

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, openlitespeed

I have downloading page:
https://example.com/preview-and-download/?key=123456789
And I want user browser as: https://example.com/preview-and-download/123456789
I Use Wordpress with OpenLitespeed

I use this function but it not work,

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', function ( $wp_rewrite ){
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
        ['preview-and-download/(\d+)/?$' => 'index.php?key=$matches[1]'],
        $wp_rewrite->rules
    );
} );
```

I'm Looking For Help with this method or other method to create virtual url from base page url:https://example.com/preview-and-download/

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

since OpenLiteSpeed can do rewrite rule , what about use something like this ?

```
RewriteRule preview-and-download/(.*) preview-and-download/?key=$1
```

It should simply rewrite `preview-and-download/something` to `preview-and-download/?key=something`